# What type of mortar should I use to repair a flat flagstone roof?

Tags: leak, roof, stone

My garage has a flat flagstone roof. It is around 100 yrs old and is leaking. There are some cracks in the mortar. What kind of concrete mortar mix should I use to stop water from seeping through?